# How do I find module implementing net interface, when there is no 'device' at /sys/class/net/eth0?

Tags: network-interface, sysfs

How do I find module implementing a net interface, when there is no `device` at `/sys/class/net/eth0`?

```
ls /sys/class/net/eth0/
addr_assign_type  carrier           iflink            speed
addr_len          dev_id            link_mode         statistics/
address           dormant           mtu               subsystem@
brforward         duplex            netdev_group      tx_queue_len
bridge/           flags             operstate         type
brif/             ifalias           power/            uevent
broadcast         ifindex           queues/
```

The `dev_id` seems promising at first but the `dev_id` for `eth0` is the same as for `lo`, the loopback interface.

The "linux" I'm dealing with seems modern enough (having a 3.3.x kernel) but it doesn't align in this particular detail with the descriptions I've seen, which apparently support things like `lspci` and other handy but rarely-used utilities.

I've read [this popular, related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97676/how-to-find-the-driver-module-associated-with-a-device-on-linux) but its answer relies on the device symlink which the system in question doesn't have.