# Looking for special files by minor number and major number

Tags: disk, block-device

Is it possible to use `find` command (or anyone else) in order to look for special devices (like disks) passing minor/major number? I thought something like this:

```
find / -type c -minor 30 -major 29
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, `find` command does not know this syntax. Is there any other way, even with other commands to obtain the same result?

Comment: read this : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125272/190518